# Oracle APEX Jet Charts not working when stacked

Tags: oracle-apex

We are finding the query results driving a JET stacked bar chart is fine, but the data points are being plotted across the wrong x values.  These erroneous data points don’t work as hyperlinks.

The issue appears to be if you have a stacked bar chart but you don’t happen to have the same series present across all the values.

So if I have apples and bananas in Q1 but only apples in Q2, things get moved around.

Surely Jet can’t expect each series to be present in each x value to work?!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the default is to plot things in the wrong X-Axis if you have different series present across each X value, unless you enable this option.   Ridiculous....

[image]